Shortcut Ctrl-k (Cut up to Line End) is copying to clip board unintentionally in Android Studio
I'm using Android Studio "Koala Feature Drop" in MacOS Sonoma 14.5 (M1 chip).
When I use Ctrl-k, the text is saved in my clipboard.
This is not happen in other apps.
My keymap setting is "MacOS".
Is there any solution?
I chanded keymap setting to others, but the problem is remain.
I use "Paste Mac App", but if I stopped this app, the problem is remain.
